# Smoothing transverse self-intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $S$ be a complex surface, and let $C \subset S$ be an immersed complex curve with a transverse self-intersection at point $P$. Let $\tilde{C}$ be a curve obtained from $C$ by smoothing the intersection at $P$. Is there a formula for computing the genus $g(\tilde{C})$ in terms of $g(C)$? --
A reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up "Riemann-Hurwitz formula"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in details in the classical book of Griffiths and Harris

[http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Algebraic-Geometry-Phillip-Griffiths/dp/0471050598](http://Griffiths-Harris%20Principles%20of%20Algebraic%20Geometry)

Chapter 4, Section 2, subsection "Curves on an Algebraic Surface"